# Which expression is correct for past version of "think"?

Tags: simple-past

I don't know which of the following expressions is correct for depicting past version of "think":

1. I *didn't think*...
2. I *don't thought*...
3. I *didn't thought*...

Comment: [Conjugation of "not think"](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-not%20think.html)

Comment: Anything with _did_ or _did not_ will keep the  infinitive version of the verb

Comment: @mplungjan Aha, I got it.

Comment: Great, It is the single biggest mistake made by all non-native speakers I have heard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'I didn't think...' is right, for present tense, and past tense is "I had not thought...." 
This is probably better on English language users: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *didn't think* is past tense.  *don't think* or *am not thinking* is present and present continuous. *had not thought* is past perfect.

Comment: So you also have _I wasn't thinking_ as a correct answer. As usual, the question which is correct depends on the context. And how about _I thought not_?